# Metaprogramming - change representation of SIMD calculation

Tags: python, metaprogramming

In doing parallel/SIMD work, I often represent calculations in the syntax below, in function `f`. However, it's a bit fault-prone to write, and I'd like to write it in the syntax defined in `g`. Is there some way to get from the syntax in `f` to `g`?

```
dta=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

VAR_ONE, VAR_TWO = range(2)

def f(ln): 
    dta[VAR_ONE][ln] = dta[VAR_ONE][ln] + 1

def g():
    VAR_ONE = VAR_ONE + 1


for ln in range(4):
    f(ln)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but here's a guess. You can create a class that has properties that allow something like what you want (I think).

Here's what I mean:

```
class Class:
    _VAR_ONE, _VAR_TWO = range(2)

    def __init__(self, dta, ln):
        self.dta = dta
        self.ln = ln

    def _getter(self):
        return self.dta[self._VAR_ONE][self.ln]

    def _setter(self, value):
        self.dta[self._VAR_ONE][self.ln] = value

    VAR_ONE = property(_getter, _setter)

    def g(self):
        self.VAR_ONE = self.VAR_ONE + 1


dta = [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]

for ln in range(4):
    inst = Class(dta, ln)
    inst.g()

print(dta)  # -> [[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```